# Finding Horizontal and Vertical Force on Bending Pipe

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pipelines

I did a Civil Engineering course some years ago and from my textbook I had a question on a bending pipe. 
The purpose of this question is to see if the way that I have calculated this is correct, as my answer is slightly out from the textbook answer.

Feedback will be much appreciated on my calculations?

I have the question below

[image: Chapt 9 - Question 27]
[image: Chapt 9 - Question 27 Figure]

Comment: @SamFarjamirad
I think you are being harsh. I have made an attempt to solve the question, it is in the scans, I just need someone to confirm if I have got this correct, what is wrong with this. It is not off topic as it is about finding Horizontal and Vertical Force on Bending Pipe. 
You should reconsider this.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad

I am just wondering if you have properly looked at my scans and see that I have my answer in them?
Can you not see that I am getting clarification on what I have is correct.
I would think better of you, if you reply, rather than just ignoring me.

I have more questions to come and would appreciate the block to be stopped, so I can post them otherwise I will be using another website for posts.

Comment: I retracted the 'Close Vote' because I was wrong about the no attempt ... . If you edit the question then maybe you get much more notice.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad
It looks like I still can't ask any more questions.

Comment: I have no authority to block users here neither any other users, maybe a technical problem I don't know . Please go to 'chat' then ask the moderators to solve the issue.